# Apache Phoenix client not able to connect with remote hbase server via Zookeper

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper, apache-phoenix, sqlline

I have a problem connecting an Apache Phoenix JDBC client (I'm using sqlline.py for test purposes) to my Hbase, from any remote computer.

The way I'm testing is the following:

I ssh to another machine running linux and then try to connect to my zookeeper quorum (which is just one machine at the moment: christianwith-KP):

```
    hadoopuser@mike-iMac ~/phoenix-4.4.0-HBase-1.0-bin/bin $./sqlline.py christianwirth-KP
    Setting property: [isolation, TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED]
    issuing: !connect jdbc:phoenix:christianwirth-KP none none org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver
    Connecting to jdbc:phoenix:christianwirth-KP
    SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
    SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
    15/08/06 14:11:36 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

After trying to connect the commandline does nothing and I get a lot off java-error message after a couple of minutes.

That's from the logfile zookeeper.out, and it seems Zookeeper is accepting the connection from the remote client running sqlline.py, as the IP-adress matches the remote computer I'm trying to connect from.

```
    2015-08-06 14:10:37,720 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /192.168.59.148:39731
    2015-08-06 14:10:37,721 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@868] - Client attempting to establish new session at /192.168.59.148:39731
    2015-08-06 14:10:37,726 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@617] - Established session 0x14f02da342b001b with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /192.168.59.148:39731
    2015-08-06 14:10:37,785 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /192.168.59.148:39732
    2015-08-06 14:10:37,786 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@868] - Client attempting to establish new session at /192.168.59.148:39732
    2015-08-06 14:10:37,794 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@617] - Established session 0x14f02da342b001c with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /192.168.59.148:39732
    2015-08-06 14:11:37,045 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /192.168.59.148:39736
    2015-08-06 14:11:37,047 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@868] - Client attempting to establish new session at /192.168.59.148:39736
    2015-08-06 14:11:37,052 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@617] - Established session 0x14f02da342b001d with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /192.168.59.148:39736
    2015-08-06 14:11:37,702 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:NIOServerCnxnFactory@197] - Accepted socket connection from /192.168.59.148:39737
    2015-08-06 14:11:37,702 [myid:] - INFO  [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2181:ZooKeeperServer@868] - Client attempting to establish new session at /192.168.59.148:39737
    2015-08-06 14:11:37,707 [myid:] - INFO  [SyncThread:0:ZooKeeperServer@617] - Established session 0x14f02da342b001e with negotiated timeout 40000 for client /192.168.59.148:39737
```

If I try to connect on my local machine everything works fine.
I made sure the 2 version of phoenix are identical...

Now let's get to my setup, I use the following versions:

- Hadoop: 2.5.2
- Zookeeper: 3.4.6
- HBase: 1.0.1.1
- Phoenix: 4.4.0

I run my zookeeper separately, and not through HBase.

This is my hbase-site.xml:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>zookeeper.znode.parent</name>
    <value>/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>christianwirth-kp</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
    <description>Property from ZooKeeper's config zoo.cfg.
      The port at which the clients will connect.
    </description>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.wal.codec</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.wal.IndexedWALEditCodec</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>phoenix.query.timeoutMs</name>
    <value>1800000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>phoenix.query.threadPoolSize</name>
    <value>8</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rpc.timeout</name>
    <value>1800000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.scanner.timeout.period</name>
    <value>600000</value>
    <source>hbase-default.xml</source>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

This is my etc/hosts:

```
192.168.60.43     hbase christianwirth-KP localhost
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

This is my output, when running jps:

```
6555 HMaster
6435 QuorumPeerMain
13614 Jps
6300 SecondaryNameNode
6658 HRegionServer
5746 NameNode
6002 DataNode
```

---start edit: 10.08.15

Another thing I just realized is, that my regionserver won't start if I just put

```
  christianwirth-KP
```

to the file HBase/conf/regionservers but it starts if I put

```
  localhost
```

in there...

---end edit: 10.08.15

I already checked a lot other topics related to my problem, but no solution seems to help.
If someone has an Idea what's going wrong here, I'd greatly appreciate the help.

Best,

Chris

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After several hours of frustration and resignation I found the solution:
You have to use the IP-Address of the machine, not the name.

I edited my hbase-site.xml as follows:

```
<property>
  <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
  <value>192.168.59.81</value>
</property>
```

My regionservers - file looks like:

```
  localhost
```

And my zoo.cfg contains:

```
  # Define Quorum-Servers
  server.1=192.168.59.81:2888:3888
```

Hope this will help some others who had the same problem of connecting to a pseudo-distributed hbase cluster remotely.

Comment: Zookeeper is just a key/value storage solution that hold the HBase master hostname and port. For debugging, your can run zkCli.sh get /hbase/master to see what happened under the hood. Usually, HBase resolves its local IP and send its hostname that Zookeeper will save.